# queue.get() doesn't remove item from queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, networkx

I recently started programming in Python (3.5) and I am trying to solve a simple Breadth first search problem in Python (see code)

```
import queue
import networkx as nx


def bfs(graph, start, target):
   frontier = queue.Queue()
   frontier.put(start)
   explored = list()

while not frontier.empty():
    state = frontier.get()
    explored.append(state)
    print(explored)

    if state == target:
        return 'success'

    print(graph.neighbors(state))

    for neighbor in graph.neighbors(state):
        if neighbor not in explored:
            frontier.put(state)

return 'Failure to find path'
```

The code returns an infinite loop where it seems that frontier.get() does not delete the item from the queue. This makes the while loop infinite, as the first value in the queue is always the start node defined in the function input. The variable state is in each while loop the same (always the start node).

What am I doing wrong? As from what I understood the queue should move from the start node to the neighbours of the start node and therefore a loop should not occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things. First, I assume everything from the `while` on down ought to be indented by one level.

If I'm reading your algorithm correctly, I believe the error is on the last line before the return. You have:

```
frontier.put(state)
```

which just inserts the node you were already looking at. I think what you should be doing instead is:

```
frontier.put(neighbor)
```

so that you explore all the immediate neighbors of `state`. Otherwise you just keep looking at the start node over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're putting the `state` value in the queue again. Change this:

```
for neighbor in graph.neighbors(state):
    if neighbor not in explored:
        frontier.put(state)  # Here you put the 'state' back!
```

to this:

```
for neighbor in graph.neighbors(state):
    if neighbor not in explored:
        frontier.put(neighbor)  # Put in the neighbours instead.
```